# Is 14.04 best release for a Netbook?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-netbook

I have dusted off an old HP Mini 1030 Netbook: Intel Atom CPU N270 (1.60GHZ x 2), 2GB RAM, NOT a snappy performer with 14.04.  Can anyone recommend a better release that is somewhat stable?  Or should I go back to Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

If If the standard 14.04 with Unity desktop enviroment does not perform well enough, you can always try either Xubuntu or Lubuntu, both are Ubuntu variants, designed to run more efficiently on low-specification computers, while built on the same 14.04 base, which has long-term support.

If you have 14.04 already installed, you don't have to reinstall ubuntu from scratch,
as you can install them both to an existing system, alongside Unity, if you have enough free space on the drive, of course.

to install Xubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

or do the same with Lubuntu, which some people find even faster

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Afterwards, when you log out try to log in, you can choose between desktop enviroments on the login screen.

See if these perform better on your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Yes 14.04 is a good release for a netbook. But I would recommend the [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) derivatives. They are lightweight.

Of course the 32 bit versions.

A netbook has integrated graphics card and Ubuntu needs quite a good card.

You can download Lubuntu directly from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso). The applications available are the same as for Ubuntu.

Some guides:

- http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Trusty
- http://www.makeuseof.com/pages/ubuntu-an-absolute-beginners-guide

This is a screenshot of Lubuntu's Software Center:

[image]

Comment: Cornelius, thanks for the response. I'm a Linux/Ubuntu beginner, groping in the dark!  Can you be more specific about an appropriate derivative product for a Netbook?  I'd like something somewhat stable.  I really liked the App store on 14.04; however, I'm guessing that that is not available on the older distractions.  Also, where is a good place for beginner help?

Comment: @Bob updated answer. If you already have Ubuntu installed follow slavmaf's instructions

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Lubuntu 14.04 on my Acer Aspire One (Atom N2600, 2GB RAM) and it runs very well.  Does everything I need it to do, quite pleased.  Been using Ubuntu (and derivatives) on various machines since version 9.04 and have been very happy overall.  I have Ubuntu to thank for my successfully migration away from Windows.

Comment: Hi. I'm considering buying an old/refurbished netbook from that era. Reading your post makes me think Acer Aspire One might be a good choice if it runs 14.04 well. Did you have any issues installing? (e.g. hardware not recognized) Also, did you upgrade the RAM to 2GB? If so, how did it run with 1GB?